# Mongoose return null sometime and many time data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have created a mongoose schema of contacts where i have created my own defined id my schema is this

```
const mongooseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true
    },
    firstName:{type:String},
    lastName: {type:String},
    name:{type:String},
    emails:[emailSchema],
    primaryEmail:{type:String},
    primaryPhone:{type:String},
    phones:[phoneSchema],
    addresses:[addressSchema],
    business:userBusinessSchema,
    memberships:[membershipSchema],
    linkedTo:linkedToSchema,
    tags:[tagsSchema],
    activities:[activitySchema],
    notes:[noteSchema],
    cases:[caseSchema],
    messages:[messageSchema],
    isArchived:{type:Number,default:0},
    transactions:[transactionSchema],
    transactionSummary:transactionSummarySchema,
    creditCards:[creditCardSchema],
    ...timestamps
},{_id:false});
```

whenever i try to save or find by id and save it sometimes store data or sometime does not store and even does not return error or exception my store code is given below

```
 const _id = "someprefix-"+contact.id;
 let c = new ContactModel({...mongoContact,_id})
    
    try{
     c = await c.save();
     return c;
    }catch(ex){
        try{
            c = await ContactModel.findByIdAndUpdate("someprefix-"+_contact.id,{...mongoContact});
            return c;
        }catch(ex){
            return ex;
        }
    }
```

please help me if anyone have solution.

Comment: Sounds like in those cases where nothing gets updated/saved there's no document with an `id` of `someprefix-"+_contact.id` ?

Comment: if there is no id then it should store inside mongodb database

Comment: Only if you pass the `upsert` option, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[findByIdAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate) will not create a new document if the provided `id` does not exist yet per default, unless you set the option `upsert` to `true`. Try changing your code to:

```
c = await ContactModel.findByIdAndUpdate("someprefix-"+_contact.id,{...mongoContact}, {upsert:true});
```